# redirect to specific domain name after the @ symbol of all email

Tags: php

I use this php code to send out domain name after the @ of all email.

```
function getDomain($domain)
{
  // Split the email after the '@' to get the email domain and send
  $parts = explode('@', $email);
  if (in_array(end($parts), $validDomains)) {
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

$host = parse_url( $Row->url, PHP_URL_HOST );
$parts = explode('@',$email);
$domain = "www.".$parts[1];
header("Location:$domain");   
?>
```

I have a php code to send domain output after the @ sign of an email... now it have been done to an extent. that it send out the below url with the domain name attached at the end of the url.

That is the main host where the files where upload and the domain name i want to to be redirectd at the end of the link.
How do i filter the other url leaving the ONLY www.google.com

as my redirect result ONLY... I dont need the other url to be sent out as output of the redirect. so now it give me error Not Found

404 not Found
Not Found

The requested URL /music/wp-content/themes/musicfile/products/www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

to redirect to another domain, you need to use the http://

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
```

in your case,

```
header("Location: http://www.$parts[1]");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This works great.

```
<?php
function getDomain($domain)
  {
  $parts = explode('@', $domain);
  if (filter_var(gethostbyname(end($parts)), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) {
      //echo end($parts);
      header("Location:http://".end($parts)); 
      }
 else{
      echo "Domain is not valid.";
     }
}

getDomain('anik@stackoverflow.com');
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because you haven't attached http:// before the domain name

Replace

```
$domain = "www.".$parts[1];
```

in your code with

```
$domain = "http://".$parts[1];
```

or

```
$domain = "http://www.".$parts[1];
```

Comment: Who is the one down voting all the answers without posting a specific reason as comment??